# Explicitly map interface member in Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to map a class which looks like below but I'm getting an exception regarding the Facility.Projects property being an interface.

> The property Facility.Projects is of an interface type IProject. If it is a navigation property manually configure the relationship for this property by casting it to a mapped entity type, otherwise ignore the property from the model.

```
public class Facility : BaseData
{
    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public Client Owner { get; set; }

    public List<IProject> Projects { get; protected set; }

    public Facility()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        Projects = new List<IProject>();
    }
}
```

I've mapped other properties via the `OnModelCreating` method for the DbContext class that `Facility` is mapped to but I'm not really seeing anything that seems like the right spot to cast this other than `HasColumnType` which also appears wrong.

```
public class FacilityRepository : BaseRepository<Facility>, IFacilityRepository
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Client>()
            .Property(f => f.Id)
            .ForSqliteHasColumnName("ClientId");

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Project>()
            .Property(x => x.Id)
            .ForSqliteHasColumnName("ProjectId");


        // area where I've tried and failed to find a good spot to do some manual casting
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Facility>()
            .Property(f => f.Projects)
            .HasColumnType<Project>(new PropertyBuilder());
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've not seen anything in the documentation that might help? Or should I, by rule, not be doing this at all?

Comment: Why use an interface here when you know the exact type that is required? Change your `Projects` property to be a `List<Project>`

Comment: Honestly, just to know if it can be done @DavidG. I'm still building out the rest of Contexts attached to this and I"m pretty sure I'm going to come across cases where I don't know the exact type. If it can't be done, it can't be done (I'm sure I'll find a way around in those cases too) - just didn't know if I was missing something big

Comment: There's a very good reason for it. If you've designed your repository as an interface in your business logic, for instance, which should actually be a normal and good thing to do. I'll go on looking for the answer now, unless you found it already but forgot to share it here. ;)

Comment: No answer yet @Arwin - wish I did. Glad to get some confirmation I'm not insane though haha

Comment: Couldn't find anything but I've worked with EF6 a lot so figured it out pretty quickly I think:

Comment: I confirmed it works in a Unit Test, so I've posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do a manual mapping of a one-to-many relationship (this example is just exposing the children on the parent, not vice versa), you can set this up as follows, and then it's pretty straightforward where the cast should be:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectState>()
            .HasMany(h => (ICollection<ProjectRoleState>)h.ProjectRoleStates)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(p=>p.ProjectGuid);
```